# Hibernate: point foreign_key to secondary table

Tags: java, database, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I have three classes:

- PlanItem
- Task
- HumanTask

It has the following hierachy:

```
public abstract class PlanItem {...}

public class Task extends PlanItem {...}

public class HumanTask extends Task {...}
```

I am using hibernate to generate two tables: "PlanItem" with all its attributes
and "Task" with all its attributes and that of its child.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class PlanItem {...}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class Task extends PlanItem {
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> properties;

}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class HumanTask extends Task {...}
```

Hibernate will make an extra table for properties but the foreign_key will point
to the "PlanItem" table. How can I let the foreign_key point to the "Task" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to map it with [`@ForeignKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html)

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
  name = "task_properties",
  joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(
      name = "task_id"
    )
  },
  foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
    foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (task_id) REFERENCES Task"
  )
)
private Set<String> properties;
```

You might need a recent hibernate version because I think being able to specify foreign keys consistently got fixed only partly in [5.0 by HHH-9709](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9709) and fully only in [5.2 by HHH-11180](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11180).

Comment: Thanks, but it still gets mapped to planItem.

Comment: What do you mean by mapped? Mean that it joins against that table or that the generated FK is still for the wrong table?

Comment: The generated FK is still for the wrong table namely "PlanItem" and not "Task"

Comment: Which Hibernate version? Many of the problems with the ForeignKeys got fixed in 5.2.8

Comment: I just tried it with Hibernate-5.2.8.Final (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.8.Final) and the problem remains.

Comment: I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11539 to track this. Maybe you can look into providing a patch? Here is the commit for HHH-11180 that should have fixed the foreign key problems: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/aeb3aee62603f4e3613ed4037f2727c817a11016

Comment: I updated the solution and actually verified it works. You have to define the `@ForeignKey` annotation on the `@CollectionTable` instead of the `@JoinColumn`

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem! However I still have a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675789/hibernate-point-foreign-key-of-table-to-secondary-table). Could you take a look at it? Thanks anyway!