# Hibernate: point foreign_key of table to secondary table

Tags: java, database, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I have three classes:

- PlanItem
- Task
- SubTask

It has the following hierachy:

```
public abstract class PlanItem {...}

public class Task extends PlanItem {
   ...
   private Set<SubTask> subTasks;
   ...
}

public class SubTask {...}
```

I am using hibernate to generate three tables: "PlanItem", "Task" and "SubTask".

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class PlanItem {

    @Id
    private String id;

}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class Task extends PlanItem {

    @Column( table = "Task" )
    private String task_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    @Column( table = "Task" )
    private Set<SubTask> subTasks;

}

@Entity
public class SubTask {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Task.class)
    private String id;

}
```

This generates the correct three tables and it generates the following foreign key relation:

```
alter table SubTask
add constraint FKrqtooosvfj0qtdol7arw1ur71 
foreign key (id) 
references PlanItem;
```

but I would like to get the following relation:

```
alter table SubTask
add constraint FKrqtooosvfj0qtdol7arw1ur71 
foreign key (task_id) 
references Task;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: How about `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task_id")`?

Comment: Tried it, but it does not work

Comment: You could still try adding `@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (task_id) REFERENCES Task"))`. Should work with 5.2.8